# Replacing particular text in all sides of a ppt using python-pptx

Tags: python, presentation, python-pptx

I am new with python-pptx. But I am familiar with its basic working. I have searched a lot but I could not find a way to change a particular text by another text in all slides. That text may be in any text_frame of a slide. like all slides in a ppt have 'java' keyword, I want to change it by 'python' using python pptx in slides.

```
for slide in ppt.slides:
    if slide.has_text_frame:
        #do something with text frames
```

Comment: Please see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73219378/python-pptx-how-to-replace-keyword-across-multiple-runs/73253266#73253266 for a comprehensive solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help, you'll need to iterate the `shape` objects in each `slide.shapes` and check for a TextFrame and the existence of your keyword:

```
def replace_text_by_keyword(ppt, keyword, replacement):
    for slide in ppt.slides:
        for shp in slide.shapes:
            if shp.has_text_frame and keyword in shp.text:
                thisText = shp.text.replace(keyword, replacement)
                shp.text = thisText
```

This example is just a simple `str.replace` of course if you have more complicated replacement/text-updating algorithm, you can modify as needed.

Comment: FYI this drops text alignment

Answer (score 2):

In addition when replacing text, you cannot simply replace it, you will loose all formatting.

Your text is contained in text_frame. Text_frame contain paragraphs, and paragraphs are made up of runs. A run contains all your formatting. You need to get to paragraph, then the run, then update text.

**"A run exists to provide character level formatting, including font typeface, size, and color, an optional hyperlink target URL, bold, italic, and underline styles, strikethrough, kerning, and a few capitalization styles like all caps."** (*see reference below*)

You'll need to do something like this:

```
prs = Presentation('data/p1.pptx') 
for slide in prs.slides: 
    for shape in slide.shapes: 
        if not shape.has_text_frame: 
                continue 
        for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:  
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                run.text=newText(run.text)                
prs.save('data/p1.pptx')
```

Official documentation(working with text): [python-pptx.readthedocs.io](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html)
Visual representation of what this means [Duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247042/how-to-keep-original-text-formatting-of-text-with-python-powerpoint)